# Using a PCB trace as a heater

Tags: pcb-design, heater, serpentine-trace

What questions should I ask to get a PCB trace as a heater?

I know the input power but I do not know the mass of the output heat.
It is to use a 24 V max and 10 A electrical supply, but the trace will be placed against an unknown mass/material and the known temperature range will be from -40 °C to heat it to 70 °C.

The company wants to use a PCB trace, not a ready-made heater, due to thickness issues.

Comment: It seems to me that a "pcb trace width calculator" (q.v.) would help, along with some sort of temperature measurement and feedback. Note that ready-made 24 V heaters are available.

Comment: I use PCB Toolkit from Saturn, But the company wants to use a PCB trace and not a ready made heater due to thickness issues. I tried to calculate it using an excel sheet but only get a resistance of 0.03 ohms and the trace gets so thin that it would burn at 10A. Should I know what the mass it is trying to heat first? But thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at heatbeds for 3D printers? Mine is just one very long PCB trace across the entire area.

Comment: Define "mass of the output heat".

Comment: An aside: SI symbol for temperature is kelvin K not degrees Celsius. @Lonewolf.

Comment: It seems worth emphasizing that 10A is the *electrical supply*, not the power requirement, and at time of writing, between comments and postings, we don't know what the actual (peak or steady) power requirement is, just that it can't be more than this for electrical reasons.

Comment: What are the requirements? Are you just trying to get "a bunch of heat" or do you have certain numbers for how much heat or what temperature you need to achieve? I think your 0.03 ohm calculation is wrong.

Comment: I was given a brief of create a PCB that fits in 100mm x 70mm to heat an unknown aluminium mass from -40C to 70C using a 24V 10A Max Power source which will have a controller to restrict the power with feedback from a PTC. A thin PCB with a 4 way connector is the only given information.  I am asking "What should I be asking the Interns for to complete this PCB?"

Answer (score 2):

Whether you use a PCB trace, a cartridge heater, a mica band heater, a swaged tubular element heater or whatever, the questions to specify it are mechanical (dimensions) and power/voltage. For a given technology of heater there will be limits (often specified as watt density) above which it is difficult to make a reliable heater. From the power and input voltage you can calculate the resistance easily.

How much power you need for a given application depends on the heat loss in steady state and the thermal mass and heat loss in dynamic situations.

Once you have the power, if it happens to be a PCB trace, you need to fit the desired resistance in the available space (and check that the watt density is not too high). [Here](https://blog.epectec.com/flexible-heater-design-watt-density-input-power-and-heater-size) is a link for a downloadable application note for FPC heater design. You might have to register to get it. Getting the resistance requires designing a (usually serpentine) pattern within PCB manufacturing limits that will result in a close enough value to the required resistance.

In cases where a controller is used, the exact resistance is not very important, a variation of 10% or 20% is acceptable, since the heater will be designed to supply more than enough power under worst-case conditions.

Comment: So I need to know the thermal Mass to know the output heat requirement as well as the input power (240W electrical maximum, and heater area of 100mm x 70mm).

Comment: 240W in 100x70mm sounds like an awfully high watt density for a PCB heater. More than 10x of that in the link I provided. So maybe your limit is actually more like 20-25W.

Comment: @Lonewolf you're really approaching this from the wrong end. You should be asking yourself how much heat you *need* instead of how much you can *produce* from your source of electrical power. As Spehro, I'm fairly certain that 240W on 10×7cm is just too much for a PCB, *no matter what method you use of heating*. Even the reflow oven used to solder my PCBs has less power density, and it's more than enough to melt all the solder on these PCBs. So, you simply can't heat up a board, using traces, or using any other methods, of that size with 240 W for any significant amount of time.

Comment: FWIW, induction heating of a PCB gets, at least a limited area (a few cm across) up to soldering temperature in fractional to several minutes, using under 50W or so (free air condition). 240W over a whole board area, I would at least expect it to cause problems with reliability, even if you're extracting the heat quickly (use thermal interface materials). *Maybe* a polyimide (flex) board thermally bonded to a metal part would be okay at that power density. So I doubt you'll be using the full capacity of the supply. We still need to know what power though.